# woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart doesnt add <form> for variable product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link` to edit the add to cart sections of product-loop on an upsell section in my cart.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'add_quantity_fields', 10, 2 );
function add_quantity_fields($html, $product) { 
    if(is_cart()){
        ob_start();
        echo '<div class="add-to-cart-container">';
        if ( !function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart' ) ) { 
            require_once '/includes/wc-template-functions.php'; 
        } 
        woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart();
        echo '</div>';
        ob_end_flush(); 
        $html = '';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

- On simple products everything works fine.
- On variabe products everything works fine as long as the variable product is the second product in the loop. The `<form>` is printed and contains the variation dropdowns and the add to cart button.

As soon as the variable product is the only product in the loop or is the first product in the loop, the output of `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link` doesn't include the variation `<form>`. Variation dropdowns and add to cart button are printed without being contained inside this `<form>`.

```
<form class="variations_form cart" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-product_id="..." data-product_variations="..."></form>
```

If this `<form>` is missing, user can't add the product to the cart even though the variation dropdowns and the add to cart buttons are shown. When user selects the variation and clicks "add to cart" WooCommerce responds with an error message "*Please choose product options by visiting %2$s.*".

I tried a lot but couldn't get behind the reasoning of this.
Why are the dropdown and button shown without the `<form>`?

*Theme is Flatsome, upsell plugin is WooCommerce Product Recommendations.*

*An obvious workaround is to include a dummy product and hide it with css, so that all other products are never the first in the loop. That worked as an ugly workaround.*

Comment: Where is your code printed if not inside the form? Before the form? After the form? It could be related to the way you print it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use ob_get_clean() instead of ob_end_flush() like that.

```
$html .= ob_get_clean();
```

The form should be printed right then. also make sure this js file is enqueued `"add-to-cart-variation.js"`

Comment: ob_get_clean() is another way that works too. ob_end_flush() and html = '' works the same as far as I am concerned. /add-to-cart-variation.min.js is loaded on the cart page, this isn't the problem either. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: Did you try to change to `$html .= ob_get_clean();`

Comment: Yes, it doesn't change the described behaviour. `ob_end_flush(); $html = '';` works too.